# three.js - draw half of an extruded circle

Tags: javascript, three.js

This will draw a cube, but how can I make it draw half of an extruded circle?

```
// half a circle
var rightfootgeo = new THREE.CubeGeometry(2, 2, 2);
for(var i = 0; i < 8; i += 1) {
    rightfootgeo.vertices[i].y -= 5;
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `THREE.ExtrudeGeometry` to extrude a shape defined by an array of points.

Here is a Fiddle that shows you how to extrude a half-circle: http://jsfiddle.net/CjZSZ/.